# e.preventDefault() inside of setTimeout()

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Scenario: Mobile - drag and drop - scrolling controls container

I have a div that contains an array of drag and drop tiles. These tiles overflow their container horizontally and I want to be able to easily scroll in the container, yet still use the drag and drop controls. I obviously don't want the container to scroll while dragging one of the controls; nor do I want the controls to prevent the container from scrolling.

To prevent page and container scroll you can use `event.preventDefault` in your `touchstart` handler. This works great and dragging the tile around does not scroll the container. Problem is you now can't scroll the container when touching the draggable tiles.

To solve this I've attempted to set a flag in the component `isDragging` that is set to true after a short delay in the `touchstart` handler and then prevent default action after that flag has been flipped. This does NOT work.

Example attempt:

```
handleDrag( e ) {
    this.dragStartTimeout = setTimeout(() => {
        e.preventDefault();

        this.setState({
            isDragging: true
        });
    }, 50)
}
```

NOTE: The `touchstart` event is bound in `componentDidMount` to the `ref` of the draggable element. This is done because you cannot `preventDefault` in passive event listeners. React uses passive listeners.

Anyone know of a work around for this?

EDIT - I figured it out. I needed to also add the `touchmove` event in the `componentDidMount` method to the element `ref`. Once that was done I needed to add an `isScrolling` flag to the component. In the `touchmove` handler I added logic to set `isScrolling` to true if `isDragging` was false. Otherwise return false if scrolling and preventDefault and proceed with drag operation if not scrolling.

```
handleDragStart( e ) {
    this.dragStartTimeout = setTimeout(() => {
        this.setState({
            isDragging: true
        });
    }, 100)
}

handleDragMove( e ) {
    if ( this.isScrolling ) return false

    if ( !this.dragging ) {
        this.isScrolling = true;
        return false;
    }

    e.preventDefault();

    // scroll is now prevent and you can proceed with drag
}
```

Comment: putting e.preventDefault inside a timeout means it's called too late, the handleDrag function has already returned by this stage without preventing default action

Comment: Yes I'm aware of this. I'm more interested in a work around to the over all problem. Thank you though. More of a way to kill the scroll nature of the touchmove event.

Comment: sorry, I just read the code first :p